# Modifying a line matching pattern and all following lines starting with character in Vim

Tags: vim, substitution

I have to prepend (comment) line matching a pattern (e.g. the string "foo") with character '*' and all following lines starting with '+'.

In the files I'm working on the syntax uses '+' as the first character of a line to mean that line is part of the preceding line, like:

```
this is a command line continuing through next lines and containing foo
+ this line continues the preciding one with other commands
+ this line continues the preciding one with other commands
this is a new command line
this is another command line
```

After the modification the text should become:

```
*this is a command line continuing through next lines and containing foo
*+ this line continues the preciding one with other commands
*+ this line continues the preciding one with other commands
this is a new command line
this is another command line
```

---

More minimal example:

```
gas
foo
+ abc
+ def
+ ghi
bar
+ qwe
+ rty
baz
foo
bor
```

Becomes:

```
gas
*foo
*+ abc
*+ def
*+ ghi
bar
+ qwe
+ rty
baz
*foo
bor
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function which comments out lines containing the pattern, but leaves already commented ones. It also check if line continuations contains pattern.

```
function! Comment(pattern) abort
  let start_line = line('.')
  let s:foo = 0

  while search(a:pattern)
    if line('.') == start_line
      if s:foo
        break
      else
        let s:foo = 1
      endif
    endif

    if getline('.') =~ '^\*'
      continue
    endif

    let f = getline('.') =~ '^+'
    s/.*/\*&
    let l = line('.')
    let i = 0


    " " This commented block is for matching lines above pattern
    "
    " while getline(l-i) =~ '^+'
    "   normal! k
    "   s/.*/\*&
    "   let i += 1
    " endwhile
    "
    " if f
    "   normal! k
    "   s/.*/\*&
    " endif
    "
    " execute ':'.l

    let i = 1
    while getline(l+i) =~ '^+'
      normal! j
      s/.*/\*&
      let i += 1
    endwhile

  endwhile
endfunction
```

Effect of `:call Comment("foo")`:

```
BEFORE | AFTER
-------|---------
foo    |  *foo
gas    |  gas
foo    |  *foo
+ abc  |  *+ abc
+ def  |  *+ def
+ foo  |  *+ foo
+ ghi  |  *+ ghi
bar    |  bar
+ qwe  |  + qwe
+ rty  |  + rty
baz    |  baz
fab    |  fab
foo    |  *foo
bor    |  bor
hello  |  hello
+ foo  |  *+ foo
abc    |  abc
*foo   |  *foo
*+ g   |  *+ g
```

Comment: Hello Jorengarenar, thank you very much for you help. I tried it out and it works, but I found a couple of problems. 1) I'd like to include the character start of line in my pattern, so that it would be ^foo, but doing that the function doesn't modify anything. 2) The function comments also lines starting with + and preceding one which matches the pattern. But I need to modify (comment) only the following lines. I'm trying to modify it by myself but don't know if I'm able doing that. If you had time to fix it... really appreciate!!

Comment: @comaante Like this?

Comment: yes, it helped me very much. there are those two points to fix. I'm working on it...

Answer (score 0):

You can select line range based on regex pattern. Sort of

```
:/foo/;/^[^+]/-1 s/^/\*
```

Here we select the lines starting from one containing "foo", until (and excluding) one not starting with "plus". Then simply substitute "the beginning of a line" with a literal "star".

Of course, that's a simplified example, and so the regex is a bit fragile.

To re-execute the last executed command you can press <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> (and after that <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>).